# How to match a class selector over an n-th child selector

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a standard table element, with the rows dynamically generated by Angular. The page looks like this:

```
<table class="myDataGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>In Service</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'offline': item.InService}">
            <td>{{item.InService}}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I have two simple CSS selectors to set my row background colors:

```
.myDataGrid tbody tr 
{
    background-color:black;
}

.myDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1)
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

And all is well, the rows alternate between gray and black. However, the "offline" class is ignored when its added:

```
.offline
{
    background-color: darkred;
}
```

It shows up in the inspector tree, but is overridden by the first classes/selectors

So I added some specificity to it:

```
.myDataGrid .offline
{
    background-color: darkred;
}
```

This works great for the black rows (selector `.myDataGrid tbody tr`) but doesn't work at all for the gray rows, it's still superseded.

So, **what selector can I write to make it work for the gray rows**? I have tried:

```
.myDataGrid .offline tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1)
```

And

```
.myDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) .offline
```

To no avail. In fact, it didn't seem to match either of them (it didn't appear in the inspector list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the space between `tr:nth-child` and `.offline` since the offline class is applied to the tr, and not one of its children.

```
.myDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1).offline
```

or

```
.myDataGrid tbody tr.offline:nth-child(2n + 1)
```

Comment: bah, tr.offline:nth-child(2n + 1)

Comment: Perfect! They both work. So I can learn, removing the space does what exactly?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET -  `tr:nth-child(2n + 1).offline` targets the *tr* with that class of `.offline`, whereas `tr:nth-child(2n + 1) .offline` (with the space) targets an element with that class *inside* the tr (or one of its children).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - no worries and this CSS [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) can come in handy!

Comment: @misterManSam Very cool. Thats likely to save me some time in the future.